# mySQL SELECT query no longer working properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a toplist, which shows the users only once in the list. I have a mySQL query which was working properly until yesterday. I have transferred my website to another host and now this query is not working like before.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM game_toplist
   ORDER BY point DESC) AS my_table_tmp
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY point DESC LIMIT 100
```

The problem is this query is not returning the highest score. It returns the score based on the users' lowest id. Here is an example of my data:

```
 id  username   point     date    gametime
1221  John       474  2015-10-04    253
1423  John       726  2015-10-04    386
```

So if the query worked properly it would return the second row (726 points) but, unfortunately it returns the first row (474 points).

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: showing some sample data in `game_toplist` table would help

Comment: Hi. There is the sample above.  You can see my sample data in the post.

Comment: the problem is with the same usernames mapped to different id's. The results you see are correct.

Comment: The id is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar query as other answer, I am starting with the query of just those users with the highest point, ordered and limited to the top 100.  From that, join back to the original table on the MATCHED user and point values.  This should only return one record per person for the top 100 users... with exception if one user has multiple records of highest point values... such as John 793 and John 793 as two different records being on file with different IDs.

To solve your issue of multiple common times, I have nested the query one level deeper.  The inner query gets the top 100 people...  That join to the game_toplist is then using the MINIMUM "ID" of the game that qualifies for the highest point for that user (in case multiple exist in the scenario).  That is finally re-joined again to the full game_toplist table, but this time on the user name AND the first game that had the highest point qualified.  This should resolve your duplicates per person issue.

```
select
      gtl3.*
   from
      SELECT
            gtl2.username,
            min( gtl2.id ) as FirstGameTimeIDWithCommonHighPoint
         from
            ( select
                    gtl.username,
                    MAX( gtl.point ) as highestPointPerUser
                 from
                    game_toplist gtl
                 group by
                    gtl.username
                 order by 
                  MAX( gtl.point ) DESC
                 limit 100 ) as Top100
              JOIN game_toplist gtl2
                 ON Top100.username = gtl2.username
                 AND Top100.highestPointPerUser = gtl2.point ) as SinglePerUser
         join game_toplist gtl3
            on SinglePerUser.username = gtl3.username
           AND SinglePerUser.FirstGameTimeIDWithCommonHighPoint = gtl3.ID
   order by
      gtl3.point DESC
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I've tried, but it gives me a white screen.

Comment: @Antee86, the only way that would happen is if there are DUPLICATE "username" values in your table because the INNER pre-query guarantees UNIQUE "userName" values with a limit of 100.  So, when joined to the game_toplist table the duplicate name would only show as I stated... the same person who had a top-100 point value AND the points were the same.

Comment: Yes, you're correct! How can I manage this problem? I need something in the query which choose only one value if the specific user has the same points. I have other field in my game_toplist table called: 'gametime'. In this field shows the users game time in seconds. So if the query can choose the lowest game time between the duplicate value than would be great. We are so close to solve this problem...

Comment: @Antee86, see revised answer and updated query to restrict to only one common highest point entry to get the earliest as you requested.

Comment: I have tried this code, but not shows anything. Anyway, I accept your answer, you helped me a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the first `order by point desc` that doesn't work inside a subquery.

And you don't need the inner select neither because you aren't changing or calculating anything

Also remove `GROUP BY username` unless you need an aggregated function like `MAX` or `COUNT`

Unless you are missing some info in your question this should be your query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM game_toplist 
order by point desc limit 100";
```

But maybe you want thisd

```
SELECT *
FROM game_toplist G
INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT username, Max(point) mp
                        FROM game_toplist 
                        GROUP BY username ) As maxP
ON G.username = maxP.username
AND G.point = maxP.mp
ORDER BY G.point DESC
LIMIT 100
```

This will probably work in mySQL but this isn't ANSI SQL standard

```
    SELECT  id,  username,   MAX(point) ,    date
    FROM game_toplist
    GROUP BY username
    ORDER BY point DESC
    LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have tried your query, but it shows the users more than once in the list. I need a query which listing the same username only once. That's why I've used `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Well then your starting query was already wrong. Your db is mysql?

Comment: If that doesnt solve your problem then you are asking the wrong question. You should provide sample data and desire output so we have something to work with, otherwise we will be guessing what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've tried, but it is not ordered by point desc. Also, listing same users more than once.